# How to add a php custom page to Wordpress

Tags: php, pages

I want to create a custom page for my Wordpress blog that will execute my php code in it, whilst remaining a part of the overall site css/theme/design.

The php code will make use of 3rd party APIs (so I need to include other php files)

How do I accomplish this?

N.B. I do not have a specific need to interact with the Wordpress API - apart from including certain other php libs I need I have no other dependencies in the PHP code I want to include in a WP page. So obviously any solution that didn't require learning the WP api would be the best one.please help me to slove this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [the **Page Templates** section of the **Static Pages** Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates).

Essentially, you create a custom page template, named something like `template-foobar.php`, which will live in your Theme's root directory, or in a one-deep sub-directory.

Inside this template file, add the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Foobar
 */

get_header();

// YOUR CUSTOM PHP GOES HERE

get_footer();
?>
```

Now your template is available to be assigned to any static Page you create.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), and add your code there. There is also an older [article by Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/13/page-templates-the-untapped-potential-of-wordpress) about that topic.

Basically, you copy the `page.php` or `single.php` of your theme, add a header to it …

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Page
*/
```

… and your code.
In the back-end you select that template for the page you want to create.